# Resource requests from webpages fail, but direct request work

Tags: javascript, html, apache, http, centos

I've installed CentOS and LAMP on an old desktop at home to practice system administration and webadmining, but I'm running into a strange problem.

I have a webpage that's no more than:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The chrome console is telling me that the request for test.js is failing. When I right click the link it gives and open it in a new tab, it correctly shows.

Is there a setting in apache that I need to set for this to work?

edit: Only thing in the logs is about the favicon

edit:

Some additional details: I'm accessing via the local ip of the machine, external script and stylesheet requests work, and all the files are in the same directory.

edit: Using fiddler, it looks like chrome isn't even sending out the request for the files.

edit: The response headers for the webpage include "Connection: close"

Comment: Are you accessing the page through your own IP? or through ´file://´ ?

Comment: @RobinJonsson, through the ip

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that file with that HTML code, and test.js are in the same directory.
I suspect that's the problem.

If you double click file on your system it's not opened via apache.
If you are opening html by 
`http://localhost/test.html`
Then chrome will search to test.js in 
`http://localhost/test.js`

Comment: This is definitely not the problem. As I mentioned, accessing the link to the file directly IS working.